# One column has multiple values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where an ID has possible multiple values in one column "Name".

This is my table

```
 -----ID------Name-----
      1       John
      1       Jim
```

I what to do this:

```
 ---- ID ----- Name-----
       1       John, Jim
```

Comment: This has been asked so many times on SO. Have you had a search or tried anything? Look up `FOR XML PATH ` and `STUFF`, or if you're on the latest version of SQL Server `STRING_AGG`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this -**

```
select a.ID,
(select b.Name +', ' from TableName b where b.ID = a.ID FOR XML PATH('')) as Name 
from TableName a
group by a.ID
```